# wp_list_pages doesn't list included page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

Ok, this is really bugging me! I wrote a function (well, modified a very similar one from the wordpress codex) which lists all child pages and the parent page whenever the page has children or is a child. That bit works fine, but what I want to do now is have it look in a custom field (add-to-nav) which has the path to another page to add to the end of the list. It checks the page and parent for that custom field.

It seems to be echoing all the right details but for some reason won't add the page to the list. Would really appreciate any help!

```
function add_sec_nav_w_extras(){

    global $post;
    global $wpdb;
    $key = 'add-to-nav';
    $addition = get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, TRUE);
    if($addition == '') {$addition = get_post_meta($post->post_parent, $key, TRUE);}
    if($addition != '') {
        $addition_page = get_page_by_path($addition);
    }
        echo("Addition page: ".$addition_page->post_title."<br/>Addition ID: ".$addition_page->ID."<br/>Current: ".$post->ID."<br/>Parent: ".$post->post_parent);

    ?><section id="secondnav_w_parent" class="fix"><ul><?php
    if($post->post_parent != "0") { // If post has parent, list that parent and all its children
        wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','include'=>$post->post_parent) );
        wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','depth'=>1,'child_of'=>$post->post_parent) );
        if($addition_page != ''){
            wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','include'=>$addition_page->ID) );
        }
    }

    else if(get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID)) { // If post is a parent, list itself and all children
        wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','include'=>$post->ID) );
        wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','depth'=>1,'child_of'=>$post->ID) );
        if($addition_page != ''){
            wp_list_pages( array('title_li'=>'','include'=>$addition_page->ID) );
        }
    }
    ?></ul></section><?php
}
```

EDIT:

Ok, so now I know why it's not showing up... I told it not to! I'm using the exclude pages plugin so that the page doesn't show up in the primary nav, and that apparently affects anything that uses wp_list_pages. So now I need to find a way to force it in there... Any thoughts?

EDIT2:

Have now disables the exclude pages plugin and using a custom menu for the primary nav. Bit of a pain but I guess not too bad. If anyone's got a better suggestion let me know!

Comment: might try get_post_custom and loop through to be sure the value you want exists? more info here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom

Comment: Thanks - turns out it was all working but I'd forgotten that the exclude pages plugin stops a page from showing wherever wp_list_pages is used. Will leave the post up here in case it helps anyone else and to see if anyone has a better suggestion to do what I'm trying to do!

Comment: @webarto yeah, it's not exactly an elegant solution but it was the only way I could think of doing what I need to without hard coding everything!